# How to obtain the latest version of the 'newtx' font package?

Tags: newtxmath, newtx

As said in the title: Is there a simple way to install the latest version of the `newtx` font package, issued on 2 May by Michael Sharpe? Or must we wait for, say, the next version of TeXLive?

Comment: Which vintage of TeXLive is installed on your computer? I have TeXLive 2020 (actually, MacTeX2020, a very close cousin of TeXLive2020), and I've had the 2020-05-02 version of `newtx` for at least several days now.

Comment: @Mico : MacTeX installs afull version of TeX Live, i.e., not a ``close cousin'' but the actual distribution. In addition it installs a separate data structure to to make it wasy to change distributions and also to add it to the PATH, etc. Of course Ghostscript and some GUI apps are installed along with some documentation.

Comment: @HerbSchulz - Thanks. I realized soon after I wrote the comment above that "fraternal twin" would have been a much more apt simile than "very close cousin". :-)